# How does the allowAutoUpdates setting differentiate?

Tags: updating

I'm not quite sure from the [documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#updates) what the difference is between 'minor' and 'build' updates.

How would the `allowAutoUpdates` general config setting have treated the update from `2.4.2726` to `2.5.2750`?

What would happen when the 2.5.x update was released, depending on whether that setting was `true`, `minor` or `build`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft's version numbers follow this pattern:

`major.minor.build`

So your update was a `minor` update and you could have blocked it with the settings `build-only` or `false`.

Comment: Right. So `true` === major.

Comment: That makes sense - wasn't aware of what the decimal points denoted. Thank you!